# Why can't I see the content of NStextView

Tags: objective-c, macos

When I use objectivec to develop MAC app, I encounter a very strange problem. When I debug locally, I use nstextview to set the text, but when I release, the text can't be seen, but it's there. Even when the mouse moves there, it can become a text input state. Right click can also search nstextview content. How to investigate this problem?
getter:

```
- (NSScrollView *)broadcastTextViewScrollView
{
    if(!_broadcastTextViewScrollView)
    {
        _broadcastTextViewScrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 100)];
        [_broadcastTextViewScrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
        [_broadcastTextViewScrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
        [_broadcastTextViewScrollView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
        [_broadcastTextViewScrollView setDrawsBackground:NO];
        [_broadcastTextViewScrollView setHorizontalScrollElasticity:NSScrollElasticityNone];
        _broadcastTextViewScrollView.documentView = self.broadcastTextView;
    }
    return _broadcastTextViewScrollView;
}

- (NSTextView *)broadcastTextView
{
    if(!_broadcastTextView)
    {
        _broadcastTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(2 * fMargin, CGRectGetMinY(self.broadcastBackgroundView.frame), NSWidth(self.view.frame) - 4 * fMargin, fMinBackgroundHeight)];
        _broadcastTextView.editable = NO;
        _broadcastTextView.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
        _broadcastTextView.verticallyResizable = YES;
        _broadcastTextView.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = YES;
        _broadcastTextView.textContainer.widthTracksTextView = YES;
        _broadcastTextView.focusRingType = NSFocusRingTypeNone;
        _broadcastTextView.selectable = NO;
        _broadcastTextView.drawsBackground = NO;
    }
    return _broadcastTextView;
}
```

addtoVC

```
- (void)configureTextView
{
    [self.view addSubview:self.broadcastBackgroundView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.broadcastTextViewScrollView];
}
```

vc is on a NSWindow

```
- (void)confugureBroadcastAttendeeWindow
{
    int styleMask = 1;
    [self.boBroadcastAttendeeWindowController.broadcastWindow setWindowStyleMask:styleMask];
    [self.boBroadcastAttendeeWindowController.broadcastWindow setContentSize:self.boBroadcastAttendeeViewController.view.frame.size];
    [self.boBroadcastAttendeeWindowController.broadcastWindow setClientView:self.boBroadcastAttendeeViewController.view];
}
```

updateUI

```
NSDictionary* params = @{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:14],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor colorWithHexRGB:kColorBlack_121212 andAlpha:1]};
    NSString* addtionString;
    if(self.broadcastTextView.string.length)
    {
        addtionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",self.broadcastTextView.string,self.message];
    }
    else
    {
        addtionString = self.message;
    }
    NSAttributedString* attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:addtionString attributes:params];
    
    [self.broadcastTextView.textStorage setAttributedString:attrString];
    
    CGFloat textViewMaxWidth = NSWidth(self.broadcastBackgroundView.frame) - 2 * fMargin;
    CGFloat textViewHeight = [[attrString string] boundingRectWithSize:NSMakeSize(textViewMaxWidth, fMaxBroadcastTextViewHeight) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin) attributes:params].size.height;
    if(textViewHeight < fMinBackgroundHeight)
    {
        textViewHeight = fMinBackgroundHeight;
    }
    if(textViewHeight > fMaxBackgroundHeight)
    {
        textViewHeight = fMaxBackgroundHeight;
    }
    CGFloat borderMinY = NSMaxY(self.okButton.frame) + fMargin;
    CGFloat textViewMarginH = fMargin + fTextViewMarginV;
    self.broadcastTextViewScrollView.frame = NSMakeRect(textViewMarginH, borderMinY, NSWidth(self.view.frame) - 2 * textViewMarginH, textViewHeight);
    self.broadcastTextView.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(self.broadcastBackgroundView.frame), NSHeight(self.broadcastBackgroundView.frame));
    self.broadcastBackgroundView.frame = NSMakeRect(fMargin, borderMinY - fTextViewMarginV, NSWidth(self.view.frame) - 2 * fMargin, NSHeight(self.broadcastTextViewScrollView.frame) + 2 * fTextViewMarginV);
    self.fromTextField.frame = NSMakeRect(fMargin, NSMaxY(self.broadcastBackgroundView.frame) + fTextFieldBottom, NSWidth(self.broadcastBackgroundView.frame), fTextFieldHeight);
    self.titleTextField.frame = NSMakeRect(fMargin, NSMaxY(self.fromTextField.frame) + fTextFieldBottom, NSWidth(self.broadcastBackgroundView.frame), fTextFieldHeight);
    self.broadcastTextView.maxSize = NSMakeSize(NSWidth(self.broadcastTextView.frame), textViewHeight);
```

Comment: can you show an example of code?

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. I noticed the order when I added the views, so it was normal for me to run locally. However, during the release, the background of the back actually ran to the top of the textview, so it was covered. I now change the ownership of the view.

before

```
- (void)configureTextView
{
    [self.view addSubview:self.broadcastBackgroundView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.broadcastTextViewScrollView];
}
```

after

```
- (void)configureTextView
{
    [self.view addSubview:self.broadcastBackgroundView];
    [self.broadcastBackgroundView addSubview:self.broadcastTextViewScrollView];
}
```

Comment: I don't know why,can anyone tell me?